# export 'time' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am new to use D3 with React. My react app is created by create-react-app.
In my react component, I import d3 using `import * as d3 from 'd3'`

My code is as below:

```
    this.xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, function (d) {
            return d[_self.props.xData];
         }))
    .rangeRound([0, this.w]);

    this.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(this.props.data,function(d){
            return d[_self.props.yData]+_self.props.yMaxBuffer;
        })])
        .range([this.h, 0]);

    this.area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function (d) {
            return this.xScale(d[_self.props.xData]);
        })
        .y0(this.h)
        .y1(function (d) {
            return this.yScale(d[_self.props.yData]);
        }).interpolate(this.props.interpolations);
```

Got the compiling error:

> export 'time' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'

I import d3 using `npm install d3 --save` under my project directory.

Anyone has ideas what's the problem?

Comment: That code is using D3 v3. You're importing D3 v4.

Comment: @bennygenel I am getting same error how to fix it ?

Answer (score 16):

You're using D3 v4. This link below is your solution to convert old version to what you using now, should be straight forward.

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 6):

Use d3.timeScale() instead of d3.time.scale()

The D3.js syntax changed in version 4 so that d3.time is no longer used.

You either need to import d3.js version 3

`npm install d3@3`

or change your code to use d3.js version 4 syntax

`d3.timeScale();`

Comment: Should be `d3.scaleTime()` now

Answer (score 4):

From version 4 you have to use *d3.**scaleTime()***

Comment: This is a very terse answer. I don't really understand, would you mind going a little bit more into detail as to what the actual problem is?

Comment: It was just a little correction of the NicoWheat answer

Comment: This type of thing is better left as a comment on another answer. Otherwise there is no real way to know that it is linked.